# Animating a toast in android?

Tags: android

Am trying to animate my toast but have been unsuccessful so far. This is what I have in my `onCreate()`:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
Animation move = new TranslateAnimation(0,100, 0, 100);
move.setDuration(2000);
move.setFillEnabled(true);
move.setFillAfter(true);
image.startAnimation(move);

Toast toast = new Toast(this);
toast.setView(image);
toast.show();
```

Have tried placing `startAnimation()` after displaying the toast, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Toast notifications use a system template to determine how they are displayed.  Short of modifying the Android source code, you can not create a special animation for your Toast message.

However, if possible you might be able to create a normal view and use that instead.  One common method is to create a new Activity that has a transparent background with your modal toast message animated and displayed however you want.

Comment: Thanks! Though I didn't quite understand your suggestion. How would I animate the toast? What I'll try is creating a Frame animation by placing my images at different locations each time.

Comment: @Kano What I was suggesting is to not use an actual Toast but an Activity with a transparent background and a child view that can be animated and made to look like a Toast.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks! Since I basically just wanted translation animation, I used Frame animations and used different images to get the translation effect.